# Place Google maps Info window below marker (with pixeloffset?)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker, infowindow

Currently, I'm working on a website where it is wanted to place the info window below the marker.
By default, when you have a map and click a marker, the info window will show above that marker, with the arrow point it to the marker. I would like to switch that around.

In the [google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add) there is a section about pixelOffset that might work But I just don't get it.
This pixel offset, where would completely 0 be? And what if you zoom out.
I can't seem to figure out how this pixelOffset works and if it is really the thing I need to place the infowindow below the marker.

So my question in general is: Does someone know how to place the google map infoWindow below the marker ? Do I need pixelOffset for it or is this something completely diffrent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to adjust offset using `pixelOffset` property, but I don't think that's what you want, because the arrow would always point downwards, not upwards to the marker.

What you want is more control over infowindow, and you won't get that using `google.maps.InfoWindow` class. There is a library called `InfoBox` which supports the same functinality as infowindow but have couple of more features, which allow for better customization.

Check [this tutorial](http://michaelsoriano.com/customize-google-map-info-windows-infobox/), the author is demonstrating very similar functionality to what you want to achieve. Basically you will create your own structure for the info infowindow, including the arrow yourself. Just using HTML and CSS. More in the tutorial.

One more thing, the link to infobox library is broken on the blogpost, because it has been moved recently to github, you can find it [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox/src). Download it to your project from there (either as `infobox.js` or `infobox_packed.js` which is the minified version).